# UITableView not showing cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I'm adding a tableView in a UIView and everything goes well upon debugging. Method '`cellForRow:atIndexPath`' is called and cell has subviews if I debug it. But while looking to UI. There's no cell on screen. Here's the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"obCodeListCell";
    JobCodeListCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[JobCodeListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"asdsada";
    cell.jobCodeLabel.text = @"test";

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
    return cell;
}
```

and here's how I've added TableView

```
- (void)setupView
{
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.scrollEnabled = false;
    _tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false;
    _tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    _tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
    _tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    [self addSubview:_tableView];
    [_tableView autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges];
}
```

now this is what I get in simulator. It should have displayed red colour at least:

[image]

Comment: it's written. Not posted here but if cellForRow is called. Then its obvious numberOfRows is being called that's why not shared here.

Comment: First check if table's constraints are correct and if it is added successfully.Then check heightforRowAtIndexPath method.If you are using Automatic Dimension make sure you have given estimatedHeight.

Comment: As you are creating UITableView using code. Please check if your tableview is added correctly. Looking at your code I feel your table's frame isn't set correctly. Or please remove this line self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init]; and try.

Comment: Have you tried to provide a frame when initiating the UITableView?